# form elements appear disabled on loading of page when they arent

Tags: html

I have a form with multiple textboxes and selects. When the page loads the all "look" disabled but they aren't. Once they receive focus the appearance changes to look enabled and stay that way even after losing focus... as they should.

What could be making them render that way on page load?

I am adding an image to illustrate the issue. I clicked on all of the form elements in the first 3 rows so you may see what happens. When the page first loads the whole form looks like the bottom rows in the image...

[form rendering issue http://www.lunargrid.com/temp/formrender.png](http://www.lunargrid.com/temp/formrender.png)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps trying to set their parameter .active = true would default their appearance.

Might be a long haul depending on the amount of stuff you got. Try it for a couple. Let me know.

Comment: I tried this... $("input").prop("active", true); ... but it didnt make any difference.

Comment: How about you use some javascript in there and set the textbox as selected? 
    Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
      $("Box1").focus();
    });

Comment: Looking deeper, seems like it may be an IE bug related issue. Try to add a Style to your form, see if it fixes everything. ie:<div><input style="padding-right: 1px;text-align:right;" id="currency" type="number" value="30" min="0" max="100" /> </div>

Comment: style didnt fix it. I even added your div example to my form as a test and it looks the same as the rest of the form. As soon as you click on it once it looks fine up until the page is reloaded.